# Why are all the USDA agents in Chew women with exaggerated physical features?

Tags: comics, chew

Most women in Chew look fairly average (e.g. Tony's sister Toni, Tony's girlfriend Amelia, Tony's daughter Olive, random passersby, etc.):

[image: Chew 19 Cover]

The women in the USDA, however, do not look average:

[image: Chew 18 Cover]

Has there been an explanation for why USDA agents are exclusively female (with the exception of John Colby, Tony's ex-partner who happens to be a cyborg), and all of the same "build<sup>1</sup>"?

<sub>[1]: They are also extremely tall.</sub>

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Fanservice

Comment: I haven't read any, but I'd guess the author is trying to make a statement about government agencies.

Comment: @Kevin it's just the USDA - Tony and Colby initially work for the FDA, Toni works for NASA, etc.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

CHEW writer John Layman initially asked me to design the first USDA agent (Agent Woo from issue 7) as a busty character. At first, I designed her boobs to be bigger than average. Then, as the issue progressed, her boobs seemed to get bigger and bigger, almost as if they had a mind of their own.

Since then, the boobs have been a running gag, used every time we break out the USDA. They're the comicbook female stereotype. Coincidentally, the lifespan for said stereotype is pretty short, as USDA agents tend to be violently killed pretty often in CHEW.

Comment: Also, I pride myself on presenting the quirkiest, possibly true-to-life women in comics in CHEW. So the USDA presents the opposite view.

Comment: Holy crap, @RobGuillory! **Huge** fan! Fun to learn that this doesn't actually have an in-universe answer, lol.

Comment: Reading this again, I'm wondering - what about the female bit? Is there a reason they are all women (except Colby)?

Comment: Awesome! Just think, if this was Wikipedia, this answer would be invalid due to a lack of citations, despite the fact you can't get more canonical than "from the horses mouth." ;)

Comment: We just thought it would be hilarious if the USDA was made up of large-breasted females with cybernetic animal sidekicks. And part of the comedy is that we never explain why.

Comment: @RobGuillory I had kind of assumed it was something of a play on the whole idea of the effect of bovine growth hormones in milk on humans, among other things.

Comment: @ChadLevy On the other hand, now Wiki can cite SFF.SE. :)